# ByteBuddy ElementMatchers for regular expressions regex

Tags: java, byte-buddy

Do you know how to use bytebuddy Advice only for elements with name matching certain regular expression?  For instance, if I need `MyAdvice` only applies for methods whose name match the expression `*.business*` I would use `ElementMatchers.nameMatches` like this:

```
final String regexp = ".*\\.business.*";
new AgentBuilder.Default()
     .disableClassFormatChanges()
     .with(AgentBuilder.RedefinitionStrategy.RETRANSFORMATION)
     .type(ElementMatchers.nameMatches(regexp))
     .transform((builder, type, classLoader, module) -> 
          builder.visit(Advice.to(MyAdvice.class).on(ElementMatchers.isMethod()))
     ).installOn(instrumentation);
```

I already tried this and it didn't work.  I don't know is this regex applies to the element full name or just for the element simple name.

Thanks guys !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use an ElementMatcher for it, they can be chained:

```
ElementMatchers.isMethod().and(ElementMatchers.nameMatches(...))
```

You can also implement your own matcher if that's simpler.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rafael.  I just have one more question: the ElementMatchers.nameMatches applies the regexp to full class name? to simple class name?... to method name?

Comment: To the method name. If you have more complex applications, simply implement your own matcher.